# Using QtDesigner generated code to set variables for another piece of code

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, pyqt, qt-designer

I generated a piece of code with QtDesigner and I would like to store user inputs in QLineEdit as variables to be used as login and password input for a selenium script.

The code looks like this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")

        self.btn_sicaf = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.btn_sicaf.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 161, 41))
        self.btn_sicaf.setObjectName("btn_sicaf")
        self.btn_sicaf.clicked.connect(lambda: SICAF())

        self.campo_cpf = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame_2)
        self.campo_cpf.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 60, 191, 21))
        self.campo_cpf.setObjectName("campo_cpf")
        cpf = self.campo_cpf.text()

        self.campo_senha = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame_2)
        self.campo_senha.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 90, 191, 21))
        self.campo_senha.setObjectName("campo_senha")
        senha = self.campo_senha.text()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.btn_sicaf.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SICAF"))

cpf = Ui_MainWindow.setupUi(self.campo_cpf.text())
senha = Ui_MainWindow.setupUi(self.campo_senha.text())

def SICAF(): 
    driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) 
    driver.get("https://www3.comprasnet.gov.br/sicaf-web/index.jsf") 
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "formLogin:txtCpf"))) 
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "formLogin:txtSenha"))) 
    campo_cpf = driver.find_element_by_id("formLogin:txtCpf").send_keys(cpf) 
    campo_senha = driver.find_element_by_id("formLogin:txtSenha").send_keys(senha)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However I can't find a way to store self.campo_cpf.text() and self.campo_senha.text() as variables and export it to my functions. I tried leaving the selenium script as a different python file and importing it's functions while giving new values to the variable in that separete python file (the selenium script), but also failed.

I tried to turn the selenium script into a method of the Ui_MainWindow class, but I didn't manage to fit the script into the class.

Running the code as it is I get this trace back error:

```
File "C:/Users/vinic/PycharmProjects/Gestão de estoque/teste.py", line 30, in <module>
    cpf = Ui_MainWindow.setupUi(self.campo_cpf.text())
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: I think your problem is conceptual: When should the "SICAF" function be executed?

Comment: When I click a pyqt button, but I omitted that portion cause I thought that would not be relevant to the variable assignment.

Comment: That part is one of the most relevant so edit your question and provide the [MRE]

Comment: Ok @eyllanesc, just fixed it.

Comment: @ViníciusLima I suggest you to carefully read the guide about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) (files generated by `pyuic` should **never** be edited). Then: 1. the `cpf = ...` line and the one after it make no sense; 2. you're calling `SICAF` in the `__init__`, but at that point the line edits don't even exist yet; 3. since `SICAF` should take the line edit contents, that function should be part of the class; 4. selenium will require some time to complete, it should be placed in another thread to avoid blocking the GUI while it's processing.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for the reply. How should I proceed in other to make the SICAF function a part of the class? I tried that but didn't suceed. I'm in doubt about what arguments I should pass.

Comment: As long as `SICAF` becomes a class method, the `send_keys` arguments can be set by accessing the line edits, for example: `driver.find_element_by_id("formLogin:txtCpf").send_keys(self.campo_cpf.text())`

Comment: Without the full traceback (that you can get by running the program from a command prompt/shell) it's hard to know what's wrong. In any case, if you didn't implement the whole selenium in a separate thread, it won't be good anyway.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks so much. It worked.

Comment: @musicamante Is there a way to upvote your comments?

Comment: @ViníciusLima according to the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (which you should carefully read, as long with [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions)), you need >=15 reputation to upvote comments. Create new (**good**) questions or give good answers, and you'll easily be granted with that permission.